# 'ip link set wlan0 up' makes terminal unusable [Arch Linux]

Tags: internet, arch-linux

I've been going through the steps trying to install Arch Linx and I cant get past the network configuration.

I got Arch to recognize my broadband card after following the instructions on [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless) using the `brcmsmac` module `iwconfig` shows that the wlan0 device is down. but when I run `ip link wlan0 up` it just prints and error message over and over again:

```
ieee80211 phy0: wlc_recv: dropping a frame with invalid src mac address, a2: 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Which makes it pretty difficult to continue the install. And I cant redirect the output, its not coming from the ip command.
From googling around the best I can tell is that it might be coming from syslog, but I don't really know. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kernel message, most likely printed by the kernel itself – you can stop these from being printed to the console with `dmesg`:

```
dmesg -n 1
```